# using for loop in GA in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using GA in Matlab to solve an optimization problem,
my objective function is to minimize cost with variable v,

```
function b = cost (v)
load ('data.mat');
c1=0;
for i = 1:N
    for j=1:1
        c1 = c1 + c(i,j)*v(i,j);
    end
end
b=c1;
```

and my constraint is const

```
function [z] = const(v)
load ('data1.mat');
Z1=1;
for i=1:N
    for j=1:1
        a(i,j) = (1-v(i,j))*t(i,j);
        Z(i,j) = ((a(i,j)+T1)/y(i,j))/(a(i,j)/y(i,j));
    end
    Z1 = Z1 * Z(i,j);
end
z=[0.7-Z1];
zeq=[];
```

Using for code for GA

```
lb=zeros(N,1);
ub=ones(N,1);
IntCon = u;
options = gaoptimset('PlotFcns',{@gaplotbestf,@gaplotmaxconstr},'Display','iter');
[v, fval] = ga(@cost,N,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@const,IntCon,options);
```

where `u=[1 2 3 4...N]`

I have already saved required data in data1.mat file.

I want to make the objective function and constraint both generalized,
otherwise I will have to write `R`,`a` and `c` value for `N` number of times.

problem is when I run it, it gives a message

```
%Error using ga (line 342)
%Too many output arguments.


%Caused by:
%Failure in initial user-supplied nonlinear constraint function evaluation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `varargout` which is variable output argument in MATLAB. Simply replace your code's output argument i.e. where you have defined your `ga` function. Instead of an array, it should be `varargout{}`. There is an example on Mathworks site about how to do [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html).

Possibly change your input and output arguments with varargin and varargout respectively. Seems like you will need this throughout.

hope this helps!

Comment: When you say you write loops and get non-optimal answers, what do you mean? From what you are saying, it sounds like your fitness function equations are probably not written correct when it was doing to loops. That's why you are getting better results with the whole equation without the loop? Also, your question showed that your error is about different number output arguments - varargout is the way to make sure it doesn't happen all the time. Unless you noticed, varargout is a cell-based implementation and accessing/mutating cell elements requires extra attention, or you'd get wrong results.

Comment: Thank for advice @hagubear, <varargout> works well within the function  but it is not giving the optimized answer. If instead of loop I write the whole equations answer is different and quite satisfactory but with the loop it gives non-optimal answers, The message after optimization shows    
Optimization terminated: average change in the penalty fitness value less than options.TolFun
and constraint violation is less than options.TolCon.  I have already tried changing <TolFun>, <TolCon> and <StallGenLimit>. But it is not working please suggest any idea which could solve this problem..